# how to resize rectangle in kinetic js,canvas 5

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

Rect is draggable,resizable even u can add or set text on it.But in fiddle textarea to take input from user is not appearing but on my workspace its working fine but if u see in fiddle problem is still there because of "simpleText" if you uncomment it, box will resize every time as per expectations but because of simpleText it resizes only 1st time and after that breaks logic.

here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/abhish20/Y2m2z/56/

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
                                    container: 'container',
                                    width: 578,
                                    height: 500,
                                    x: 10,
                                    y:18
                                  });
                                var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
                          stage.add(layer);

                    var group = new Kinetic.Group({         
                        draggable : true,                                    
                    });     
        var relativeX=0;
        var relativeY=0;

                var box = new Kinetic.Rect({                             
                    x : relativeX,
                    y : relativeY,
                    offset : [ 50, 25 ],
                    width : 100,
                    height : 50,
                    fill : 'yellow',
                    stroke : 'black',
                    strokeWidth : 1,    
                    name:"comment"                      
                });

                group.add(box); 
              layer.add(group);
        layer.draw();


        var simpleText = new Kinetic.Text({
                        x : relativeX,
                        y : relativeY,                       
                        text : '',
                        fontSize : 15,
                        fontFamily : 'Calibri',
                        width:box.getWidth(),
                        height:box.getHeight(),
                        padding: 4,
                        fill : 'black',
                        id:"textBox"

                });
                 group.add(simpleText);
                        layer.draw();

                var circle1 = new Kinetic.Circle({          
                    x: relativeX+50,
                    y:relativeY+25, 
                    x : 50,
                    y : 25,
                    radius: 4,
                    fill: 'red',
                    stroke: 'black',
                    strokeWidth: 1,                        
                    draggable: true,
                    visible:false
                });

                group.add(circle1);                                         
                layer.draw();

                circle1.on("dragmove", function () {                              
                        var pos = this.getPosition();
                        var x = pos.x;
                        var y = pos.y;
                        var rectX = box.getX();
                        var rectY = box.getY();
                        var x1= x - rectX;
                        var y1= y - rectY;                                                                  
                        box.setSize(x1+50,y1+25);               
                          layer.draw();




                        var textX=simpleText.getX();
                        var textY=simpleText.getY();
                        var x2= x - textX;
                        var y2= y - textY;      
                        simpleText.setSize(x2,y2); 

                        var circle1X=circle1.getX();
                        var circle1Y=circle1.getY();
                        var x3=x-circle1X;
                        var y3=y-circle1Y;
                        circle1.setSize(x3,y3); 
                        layer.draw();                                
                    });     



                box.on('mouseover', function() {
              document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';                
                      });

                box.on('mouseout', function() {
              document.body.style.cursor = 'default';                     

                       });

                circle1.on('mouseover', function() {
              document.body.style.cursor = 'se-resize';
                });
                circle1.on('mouseout', function() {
              document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
                });





              group.on('click', function(evt) {                              
                      var shape =circle1.getVisible();               
                      if( shape==false)
                             {                                  
                              circle1.show();
                              layer.draw();   
                              $('html').on('keydown',function(e){   

                                   if(e.keyCode === 46){                             
                                        group.destroy();
                                        layer.draw();                                                 
                                    } 
                             });

                             }else{
                                circle1.hide();
                                layer.draw();
                               }     
                       circle1.setVisible(false);

                 });                



                  group.on('dblclick', function() {                                                     
                          if (hasInput)  
                              return; 
                              addInput();   

                        }); 



                  var canvas = document.getElementById('canDemo');
                  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
                  font = '14px sans-serif',
                  hasInput = false;

                 function addInput() {                        
                  var input = document.createElement('textarea');   
                  var x=box.getX();
                  var y=box.getY();
                  input.id="comment_area";
                  input.type = 'textarea';
                  input.style.position = "absolute";    
                  input.style.left = x+220+ 'px';
                  input.style.top = y+171+ 'px';
                  input.style.height=300;
                  input.style.zIndex="3";                               
                  input.onblur= handleEnter;                    
                  document.body.appendChild(input);
                  input.focus();



                if(simpleText.getText().length!=0)
                    {
                     $("#comment_area").val(simpleText.getText());
                    }
                  hasInput = true;

              }


             function handleEnter(e) {      
                var keyCode = e.keyCode;

                  simpleText.setText( $("#comment_area").val());                         
                  drawText(this.value, parseInt(this.style.left, 10), parseInt(this.style.top, 10));                             
                  document.body.removeChild(this);
                  hasInput = false;

              }

              function drawText(txt, x, y) {  
                  ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
                  ctx.textAlign = 'left';
                  ctx.font = font;
                  ctx.fillText(txt, x - 4, y - 4);                        
                  layer.draw();

              }



              $('#comment_area').keypress(function (e){
                    if(e.keyCode === 13){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        this.value = this.value.substring(0, this.selectionStart)+"\n";
                    }

                });
```

my concern is i am grouping all elements together to behave like single component so it causing a problem but i want working code in group form only.

please suggest

here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/abhish20/Y2m2z/56/

Comment: Please add your code. Placing your text inside code tags not only makes your post unreadable, but is a sad way of adding a fiddle without code.

Comment: you can go through by fiddle as well as code :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your code.

circle1.setSize(x3, y3);

if x3 or y3 are  === 0, then the circle vanishes.

Comment out that line, then the code works.

You can test your code to find issues like this by inserting... console.log(x3,y3) or whatever...

Comment: Do you know how to take return value outside of function? like        var c myRect.on("click",function(){c=a+b }); alert("addition is:" +c);  here consider myRect is rectangle drawn on canvas. means i want to take return value true or false in my code so using that i can write condition outside of function like if(true)..

Comment: I set up my code a little different than anything I've seen online. I am not really a programmer. But yes I have figured out how to do that. I have a controller function which stores variables, and they are accessible to all other functions. There's more than 1 way to do this. For instance... see www.pixycakes.com/cakedesigner or search for "three.js editor" -- in cakedesigner, pixy is the main function and stores variables that all the rest can access. "this.uiScale" for instance. anything can access that by calling "pixy.uiScale" and the variable is accessible. hope that makes sense...

Comment: or. Since Pixy calls "Oven" then anything can also access Oven variables. For instance I can call "pixy.oven.getCakeData" from anywhere else in my (what look like) totally self-contained functions.

Comment: I am actually just learning about javascript and 'scope' you can find lots of articles about Variable Scope online. I know very little.